# How are SQL Server sysschedules intervals calculated?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This table: [sysschedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx)

If the `freq_type` is 8 (weekly) then `freq_interval` is 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 for Su,M,T,W,Th,F,S.

But when `freq_type` is 32 (monthly relative) then `freq_interval` is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 for Su,M,T,W,Th,F,S, weekday, weekend.

Why is this? Is there some sort of calculation occurring to reduce query complexity?

If so, how? (sry if I sound clueless, building a recurring events system is melting my brain)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `freq_type` is 8, then the job can occur on **one or more** days - so there needs to be a way to represent multiple days in the `freq_interval` column. This is done by assigning each day a power of two value, and so multiple values can be added together unambiguously. E.g. for something that occurs on Monday, Wednesday and Friday, the value would be 2+8+32 = 42. (Your question has the wrong values assigned to the days)

If `freq_type` is 32, then only a single option can be selected - **one** day of the week, or day, weekday or weekend. Since multiple values *cannot* be combined, a simpler representation can be used.

Comment: So a query to get all events on a Tuesday could be SELECT * FROM EventTable WHERE freq_interval  = [3 or 4]? Because 3 if freq_type is 32, 4 if it's 8. Correct?

Comment: To get all events occurring on a Tuesday, you'd query for `WHERE (freq_type=32 AND freq_interval=3) OR (freq_type=8 AND freq_interval&4 = 4)`. You *should not* attempt to query `freq_interval` without also considering `freq_type`.

Comment: Great, that makes perfect sense. How are events which happen once every other Tuesday (every 2 weeks) represented with this model? Perhaps `WHERE (freq_type=32 AND freq_interval=3 AND freq_relative_interval=5)`? freq_relative_interval 1 = First, and 4 = Third. (After typing all this out, it seems this wouldn't answer the question. Instead, only returning every first and third Tuesday...). Hmm...

Comment: how are multiple days handled in a query? For example, if I want all events on Tuesdays, I'd `WHERE (freq_type=32 AND freq_interval=3) OR (freq_type=8 AND freq_interval= 4)` but what if an event has a freq_interval of 20 (which is Tues and Thurs)? Do I have to query for all possible combinations of Tues, or is there a better way?

Comment: @Chad - in my previous comment I showed how to query for Tuesdays - `freq_interval&4 = 4`. Note the `&4` - this performs a bitwise AND against the `freq_interval` before the comparison.

Comment: Oh, I am not familiar with "bitwise AND"... I'll have to look into that. Any good links to info about it? Thanks!

Comment: @Chad - the usual place to start would be [binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system), then [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). Then you might re-read my answer and understand the significance of assigning each day a power-of-two value.

Comment: THANK YOU! You have no idea how long I have been trying to find an answer to this! I had not heard of bitwise operators before, but they make perfect sense for a lot of scenarios I need. Thank you!

Comment: @Chad - it should be noted that I wouldn't generally recommend this type of coding in an SQL database. This table is hardly a paragon of good database design. Having multiple pieces of data encoded into a single column isn't really the way to do things.

Comment: replace ^ with AT symbol...Bitwise AND example (code in comment denied):
    DECLARE ^INT INT = 42

    DECLARE ^ENUM_INTERVAL TABLE (
  IntervalValue INT, 
  IntervalDescription VARCHAR(20)
 )

 INSERT INTO ^ENUM_INTERVAL 
  VALUES
  ( 1, 'Sunday'),
  ( 2, 'Monday'),
  ( 4, 'Tuesday'),
  ( 8, 'Wednesday'),
  ( 16, 'Thursday'),
  ( 32, 'Friday'),
  ( 64, 'Saturday')

 SELECT ^INT&IntervalValue, 
  ^INT, 
  IntervalValue, 
  IntervalDescription
 FROM ^ENUM_INTERVAL
 WHERE ^INT&IntervalValue > 0

Comment: The following has quite a nice function that comes up with a description of schedules (which can be joined to other tables for job/schedule reporting): https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1622/generate-sql-agent-job-schedule-report/